# AngularJS stuck on ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have a table that dynamically produces rows based on certain criteria.  However, I want the rows to be limited to just 5 rows maximum.  If there are more than 5 rows, I want a link to appear at the bottom of the table that says "More Articles".  If there are 5 rows or less, I don't want the "More Articles" link to be visible.  I'm pretty sure I have to use a ng-if here, but not sure how to construct it.  Any suggestions?

```
<table class="table table-sm table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="wrap-header"><big class="big-text">My Benefits Articles</big></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="item in data.list track by $index | limitTo: 5">
    <tr>
      <td><a ng-href="{{item.url}}"  target="_blank"> <img class = "icon" src="{{item.icon}}" height="30" width="30"> {{ item.short_desc }}</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div ng-if="/* What goes here? */">
  <a ng-href="/fedhc/?id=kb_category&kb_category={{item.parent}}" target="_blank">More Articles <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div ng-if="data.list.length > 5">
    <a ng-href="/fedhc/?id=kb_category&kb_category={{item.parent}}" target="_blank">More Articles <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
 </div>
```

Comment: This would only let you click the button once. Wouldn't it? What if there's more than 10 posts total?

Comment: Here our requirement limits to 5

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an ng-show which shows something meeting a certain criteria.
This is better practice than using ng-if for showing content.

```
   <div ng-show="data.list.length > 5">
       <a ng-href="/fedhc/?id=kb_category&kb_category={{item.parent}}" target="_blank">More Articles <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
    </div>
```

Here is documentation for both:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, i would use a variable to determine how many posts are shown. This can be achieved by changing `limitTo: 5` to `limitTo: shownPosts` (remember to declare it and set to 5 in your scope aswell)
Then, you'd want to check if you got more posts than are visible.
`<div ng-if="data.list.length > shownPosts">`
**Side note:** You want to increment the shownPosts variable by 5 every time you click the button.